# Will installing "Extensions for SharePoint Products" cause user interruption?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, installation

I need to integrate TFS with our production SharePoint server. I know that I need to install the "Extensions for SharePoint Products" which I believe installs the templates and lets me configure my projects to point to SharePoint. I found a great article on [installing the extensions.](http://geekswithblogs.net/hinshelm/archive/2010/05/03/integrate-sharepoint-2010-with-team-foundation-server-2010.aspx)

**Will installing the extensions cause any Application Pool Resets or will it cause any user interruption?** It's a production server and I don't want to affect any users.

Configuration:

- TFS 2010
- SharePoint 2010
- Server 2008 R2

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since it is installing features at the farm level, it will reset the application pool.  If you don't want to affect your users, you should do this durning off hours if possible.

Comment: Thanks I was pretty sure it would and the confirmation helped a ton!